# SQLDeveloper: Connection node vanished from Connections tab

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently switched to a new computer. Oracle SQLDeveloper (18.2) was one of the software folders that I copied from old computer.
But when I tried opening the **sqldeveloper.exe**, I see the **Connections** node is not there in the **Connections** tab.
[image]

I tried doing "Reset Window To Factory Settings", Deleting SQL developer folder from User/AppData/ folder. But no help. Right click, Left click in the Connections tab does not give any popups.
I even tried deleting the entire folder and unzipped the original zip file I had backed up long back, but did not help either.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: You need to export/import connections from old machine to new machine. Create an xml file by clicking on connections on old machine and click export .

Answer (score 0):

Delete your connections.xml file in your AppData, Roaming Profiles folder in the system18... directory.

Start sqldev.

Then on old machine, export connections.

Then bring that file to your new machine.

Import.

[Step by step here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/07/moving-your-sql-developer-preferences-between-machines/)